# egrep - regex filtering characters only working when run via cron?

Tags: regex, bash, cron

This is baffling to me, please help :-)

I have a program which sometimes runs by CLI, and sometimes though cron, both as the same user, and both in the bash.

In cron I use `SHELL=/bin/bash` to force bash.

The offending command within the script is:

```
egrep -v "$^" playlist.txt | egrep -v "[^ -.[:alnum:]]" >>formattedPlaylist.txt
```

Basically, it should remove all blank lines from the playlist, then remove any line which contains anything other than [A-Za-z0-9 - .].

For some reason, when run as a user from cli, this does not filter out many characters, whereas if cron runs it, it works exactly as expected.

The characters which are not filtered out are:

`% $ # ! * & ( ) '`

Any ideas??

Comment: What do you mean removing anything other than  [A-Za-z0-9 - .]? Do you want to remove even line contains spaces?

Comment: I doubt this has nothing to do with your problem, but the `egrep` command is deprecated : you should use `grep -E` instead.

Comment: `[:alnum:]` could depend on the LOCALE of current user, try `LANG=C ... your command` in the shell session.

Comment: @Saleem - sorry, spaces are allowed, I just forgot to mention it...

Comment: @LarsFischer - I will give that a shot asap- but that sounds right.

Comment: I'd suggest you using sed. see post below

Comment: So you want to keep these `A-Za-Z0-9\-\.%\$!*&() '`characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 sed  '/[^-A-Za-z0-9.\x27 ]/d;/''/d;/^\s*$/d' playlist.txt > cleaned_playlist.txt
```

Input text:

```
A goat
232423

-sdf-g
Here it goes
'keep me
$ let it go
\ this one too
```

Output:

```
A goat
232423
-sdf-g
Here it goes
'keep me
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I needed. The characters that are allowed are:  "A-Z" "a-z" "0-9" "-" "." and the any white space.

Comment: Thank you :-) - Although this doesn't really answer my question, it does technically solve the problem. I will mark your answer correct, if you can clarify 2 things: Why does the current command not filter out "\" (literal back-slash) - and how can I allow the single quote character (apostrophe)?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I need to allow the apostrophe character, not filter it out. And I don't want to append the file, it needs to output to new file. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107359/discussion-between-saleem-and-asimovwasright).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your locale explicitly.

```
LC_ALL=C egrep -v "$^|[^ -.[:alnum:]]" playlist.txt >>formattedPlaylist.txt
```

I also simplified the command by merging the two regular expressions, but the locale fix is the answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion did not filter out many of the characters.